# How to get generic type name in TypeScirpt?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I'm working on a webpack loader that generates TypeScript types. I need the name of a generic type or any metadata about types in order to return a correct type base on the input of `applyStyle(Button)`, so if the input is `Button` then the return type should be `FC<AProps>` if the input is `Input` then `FC<BProps>`. I can not import type of Button/Input into my **styles.scss.d.ts** to extends them like this: `type PickType<P> = P extends ButtonType ? AProps : never`.

**styles.scss.d.ts**

```
import {FC, ComponentProps} from 'react'

interface AProps {
  type: 'primary' | 'secondary'
}

interface BProps {
  hasIcon: boolean
}

type PickType<P> =
  typenameof P equlas 'ButtonType' ? AProps : // <- it is wrong, here need help 
  typenameof P equlas 'InputType' ? BProps : 
  never

interface ApplyStyle {
  <C>(Comp: C): FC<PickType<C>>
}

export declare const applyStyle: ApplyStyle
```

**index.ts**

```
import {applyStyle} from './styles.scss' // applyStyle is defined in styles.scss.d.ts

interface ButtonProps {
  isBoo?: boolean
  foo: `hello` | `world`
}

type ButtonType = FC<ButtonProps>

const Button: ButtonType = props => (
  <button {...props}/>
)

const StyledButton = applyStyle(Button) // FC<AProps>

const StyledInput = applyStyle(Input) // FC<BProps>
```

Comment: You can't access the *name* of a type this way at all.  When you say "I cannot import type of Button/Input", what do you mean?  Why not?  Can you refactor so that things import types from a common file?

Comment: I'm also not sure what `InputType` is supposed to be here.

Comment: So, there's probably a better way for you to package these things, perhaps with declaration merging.  But in any case, you can't access *names*; you'll need to talk about *structure* instead.. maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/DWKGyW)?  I think maybe you need a stackblitz or codesandbox [mcve] people can play around with if you want more specific help here.  Are you allowed to modify the `ButtonType` or `ButtonProps` types at all?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the real world usage based on how this is typed in your example. `ApplyStyle` takes a component that has props `ButtonType` or `InputType` and returns a component that has props `AProps` or `BProps`.  It takes a `Button` with props `isBoo` and `foo` and returns one with props `type` only.  Surely we want to be passing through other props like `onClick` and `children`, right?  In the body of your `applyStyle` function, you are mapping the `type: 'primary' | 'secondary'` to the props `isBoo` and `foo`.  So it stands to reason that we want to require `type` if we ...

Comment: ...need to generate `isBoo` and/or `foo`.  That is what @jcalz is getting it with `P extends { isBoo?: boolean } ? AProps`.  We should be able to map from the outputs to the expected inputs some logical way.  There is also some confusion here between the component type and the props type because `C` is the component and you call `PickType<C>`, so `PickType` would need to be looking at the component, not the props.

Comment: My advice: think about what `applyStyles` actually does in its implementation and use that to figure out your mappings.

Comment: @jcalz @Linda well there is the use case you can check it [here](https://github.com/sultan99/stylin) so the idea is to style component with new props but keeping its properties & styles. I could import types from style.scss.d.ts `applyStyles<AProps>(Button)` but I wanted to make it more simple without any extra imports.

Comment: I tried to override function `interface ApplyStyle {<C>(Comp: C): FC<PickType<C> & AProps>;  <C>(Comp: C): FC<PickType<C> & BProps>}` but it didn't work

Comment: I strongly suggest coming up with a [mcve] in the form of a cloud IDE project or code that can be dropped easily into a standalone IDE, to lower the barrier for someone to demonstrate your situation for themselves and work on a solution.  A github repository is likely not minimal, nor will people be inclined to clone a repo just to answer an SO question.